# Grid builder HTML/JS

Tags: grid, interface-builder, builder

I'm looking for live grid builder.

E.g.: I need 9 boxes [image]

And with options to possible combine some blocks. 
[image]

Comment: As in you want a program that sets up your html and css for you?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a cook-to-order restaurant. If you need something written for you, hire a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's dare I say, hundreds of CSS grid libraries/frameworks.  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/),  [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [960 Grid](http://960.gs/), [Pure](http://purecss.io/grids/)..  Bootstrap and Foundation are probably the most widely used with tons of documentation.  There's also [Gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) and [Gridster](http://gridster.net/) that are Javascript plugins that are more for widget building.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't want create for me. Just maybe exist any library or something other.